# Android ask for permission at startup ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I have an ionic cordova app that needs permission for location - so I use the cordova-plugin-geolocation. However, I want to check and ask for permission at the app start-up not when the user actually hits a location-button in the app. I see some suggestions on code, but how / where do I add code to my ionic cordova project in order to check these permissions and ask for it?

Answer (score 1):

check for permission in the constructor of your root page.